# How to listen for more than one HTML select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, select

I have more than one select html tag ( basically 3 right now) and i want to filter my table using the selected values**   (group of html selected tags) using Ajax request ...

**ex) filtering using Gender , Location , Season**

My question is how to make this done, on the same time not duplicating my code for each select tag?

Comment: what u have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it using following code.

```
$("select").change(function(){
   var location = $("LOCATION_SELECTOR").val(); //selector using ID/Class/Name
   var gender= $("GENDER_SELECTOR").val();
   var season= $("SEASON_SELECTOR").val();


   $.ajax(...) // use above 3 values to post the data.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one ajax for any of the dropdown change as:

```js
$("select").on('change',function (){
  var selectedValue = $(" :selected").val();
  ajax({
    // Do post for submitting the value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Doing this you can change whatever select you have but post only for one on change. This could also help you with not duplicating the select field codes for posting.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript **array.sort()** to sort your elements take refrence from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#fruits').change(function(e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();
        console.dir(selected);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="true" id="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
    <option value="grape">Grape</option>
    <option value="watermelon">watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks all of your time and effort guys :) ...  i found that  @K D answer ... solved my problem  , so i will give him the credit ^_^ ,